# Problema com controller no Scene builder no caso ele não reconhece eda erro

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code, scenebuilder

Olá pessoal aparentemente estou tento problema para o Scene builder ver meu package controller, arquivo: LoginVerification.java e ja olhei o caminho e a principio não aparenta ser a causa raiz do problema.OBS: o meu sistema operacional é o kali caso isso ajude e estou na IDE VS CODE e sim ja tentei no eclipse mas dai piorou ate pra instalar.

Segue o codigo abaixo:

login.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="516.0" prefWidth="327.0" style="-fx-background-color: PURPLE; -fx-border-color: BLACK; -fx-border-width: 7;" stylesheets="@src/main/java/login/css/Login.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="greentech.login.controller">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="130.0" fitWidth="140.0" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../img/greentechlogo_LoginArea.png" />
         </image>
         <effect>
            <ColorAdjust contrast="-0.13" hue="-1.0" />
         </effect>
      </ImageView>
      <Line endX="69.0" layoutX="163.0" layoutY="190.0" startX="-69.0" />
      <Line endX="100.0" layoutX="164.0" layoutY="213.0" startX="-100.0" />
      <Text fill="WHITE" fontSmoothingType="LCD" layoutX="93.0" layoutY="207.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Smart Solutions">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Italic" size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Pane layoutX="64.0" layoutY="247.0" prefHeight="226.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: WHITE;" stylesheets="@src/main/java/login/css/Login.css">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="user" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="47.0" />
            <Text layoutX="15.0" layoutY="43.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ID/Login" wrappingWidth="71.5234375" />
            <TextField fx:id="password" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="113.0" />
            <Text layoutX="15.0" layoutY="109.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Password" wrappingWidth="94.5234375" />
            <Button fx:id="submit" layoutX="54.0" layoutY="165.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#submit" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="85.0" stylesheets="@../styles/Styles.css" text="Login" />
            <Label fx:id="errorLabel" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="162.0" textFill="RED" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

loginverification:

```
package greentech.login.controller;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class LoginVerification {

    @FXML
    private TextField user;

    @FXML
    private TextField password;

    @FXML
    private Label errorLabel;

    @FXML
    private Button submit;

    String userValue;
    String passValue;

    //teste de login com usuario ficticio
    String users[] = {"adm", "comun", "teste", "adm2"};
    String passwords[] = {"123", "456", "!@#", "abc"};


    // Pega o valor dos campos preenchidos na tela de login e 
    // usa a funcao verifica para ver se correspondem e segue para a proxima tela
    // se não aprecera uma tela de erro
    @FXML
    void submit(ActionEvent event) {
        
        userValue = user.getText();
        passValue = user.getText();

        verifica(userValue, passValue);
    }

    public void verifica(String usuario, String senha){

        for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            if(userValue == users[i] && passValue == passwords[i]){
                
                
                
            } else{
                errorLabel.setText("Usuario e/ou senha errado");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo! Existe algum erro de log? Ou o erro é de compilação mesmo? Pode falar mais sobre ele?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que consegui achar a soluçao pois estava com o mesmo problema.
Como o Scene Builder tem adoraveis limitações, o jeito e colocar onde esta seu controller no arquivo .fxml que você desejar:
Exemplo

```
fx:controller="javafxadvanced.advanced.main.controller.index"
```

Eu tambem coloquei no modulo-info.java o seguinte trecho, porem não sei se faz diferença:

```
opens javafxadvanced.advanced.main.controller;
```

Segue print de como esta organizados meus arquivos:
[[image: Imagem mostrando arquivos/código na IDE]
<sup>clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrTXG.png)

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).